# Binary operator '|=' cannot be applied to two 'UIAccessibilityTraits' operands

Tags: ios, swift

I just updated to xCode 10 and instantly got this error "Binary operator '|=' cannot be applied to two 'UIAccessibilityTraits' operands"
The error appears in the 4th line of code:

```
func setAccessibilityView() {
    self.addSubview(accessibilityView)
    accessibilityView.isAccessibilityElement = true
    accessibilityView.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraits.button
}
```

Comment: If you are using the Pod "Floaty", what im sure you do, then change accessibilityView.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraits.button

with 

accessibilityView.accessibilityTraits.insert(.button)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

These are not Objective-C bitmasks. `accessibilityTraits` is of type `UIAccessibilityTraits` which conforms to `OptionSet` which in turn conforms to `SetAlgebra`.

To add a value to the existing values, replace:

```
accessibilityView.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraits.button
```

with:

```
accessibilityView.accessibilityTraits.insert(.button)
```

If you wanted to add multiple values, you can do:

```
accessibilityView.accessibilityTraits.formUnion([.button, .selected])
```

If you want to set the traits to a specific set, then do:

```
accessibilityView.accessibilityTraits = [.button, .selected] // whatever options you need
```

To remove a value, use:

```
accessibilityView.accessibilityTraits.remove(.button)
```

Answer (score 3):

`|=` is the "bitwise-OR and assign operator", applicable to binary integer types only. In Objective-C `accessibilityTraits` is a bitmask. In Swift it has been updated to an `OptionSet` with a nicer syntax:

```
accessibilityView.accessibilityTraits.insert(.button)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the short term if you have a lot of code to migrate you can use operator overloading to reimplement the missing operators:

```
#if swift(>=4.2)
    public extension UIAccessibilityTraits {
        public static func |= (left: inout UIAccessibilityTraits, right: inout UIAccessibilityTraits) {
            left = left | right
        }

        public static func | (left: UIAccessibilityTraits, right: UIAccessibilityTraits) -> UIAccessibilityTraits {
            return UIAccessibilityTraits(rawValue: left.rawValue | right.rawValue)
        }

        public static prefix func ~ (trait: UIAccessibilityTraits) -> UIAccessibilityTraits {
            return UIAccessibilityTraits(rawValue: ~trait.rawValue)
        }
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

`|=` is the **bitwise-OR and assign operator**", applicable to binary integer types only. In Objective-C `accessibilityTraits is a bitmask`.

In `swift 4.2` you can use like below:

```
accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraits(rawValue: accessibilityTraits.rawValue | UIAccessibilityTraits.button.rawValue)
```

Comment: then what will be the equivalent of accessibilityTraits.remove(.selected) ?

Comment: This solution is called out under known issues in the Swift 4.2 Migration Guide https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift4.2/